# How do we exclude some unit tests from running in an Android project

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

We are in

- gradle version 5.5
- android gralde plugin 3.5.0

And I can run a subset of tests with

```
./gradlew :app:testDebug --tests="*Fragment*" --tests="*Activity*"
```

But I want to find a way to do the inverse i.e not run the tests that is matching these options, something like

`./gradlew :app:testDebug --notTests="*Fragment*" --notTests="*Activity*"`

There is an excludeTests option https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html but I can't use these in an android project, these are pure java options.

**Some context:** On our CI we are seeing memory issues with unit tests and we are suspecting roboelectric, so we are trying separate pure unit tests vs roboelectric tests to try and isolate the issues or apply specific fixes for the jobs.

Comment: What test runner are you using? There's typically a way to specify test suites or profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's not the nicest solution but I did manage to make it work by doing the following.

Annotate your test class with

```
@Category(my.package.WhateverClass) // I personally used Robolectric
```

Add the following to your root `build.gradle`

```
if (project.gradle.startParameter?.taskRequests?.args[0]?.remove("--robolectric")) {
    subprojects
            .all {
        it.tasks
                .withType(Test)
                .configureEach {
            println "Configuring task $it.name"
            useJUnit {
                includeCategories 'my.package.WhateverClass'
            }
        }
    }
} else if (project.gradle.startParameter?.taskRequests?.args[0]?.remove("--unit")) {
    subprojects
            .all {
        it.tasks
                .withType(Test)
                .configureEach {
            println "Configuring task $it.name"
            useJUnit {
                excludeCategories 'my.package.WhateverClass'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Run tests as
`./gradlew project:testDebug --robolectric`
or
`./gradlew project:testDebug --unit`

If you don't add anything it will run all tests by default

If you have more time, you could probably create a task, that extends from test and adds the same configurations.

Note: The `.remove('--robolectric')` is there because Gradle will think its a task since it's not defined as a flag in any task